# ARM v7 BKPT instruction doesn't work correctly on Linux 2.6.35

Tags: linux, arm

I have a problem is connected with BKPT instruction on ARM v7 on Linux 2.6.35. The main reason is that the address of fault instruction (bkpt) is not correct and does not correspond to ARM v7 manual.

Here is the steps for reproducing:

1. Redefine OS SIGBUS handler to my SIGBUS handler:

   ```
   void InitSigBusHandler() {  
       struct sigaction sa;  
       memset(&sa, 0, sizeof(sa));    
       sa.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;  
       sigfillset(&sa.sa_mask);  
       sa.sa_sigaction = SigBusHandler;  
       sigaction(SIGBUS, &sa, NULL);
       }
   ```
2. Use the inline _asm and put the "BKPT" instruction into code in **main()** function:

   ```
   int main(int argc, char **argv)  
   {
        InitSigBusHandler();
        __asm
        (
             "bkpt\n\t"
        );

        return 0;
   }
   ```
3. Here is my SIGBUS handler:

   ```
   void SigBusHandler(    
       int         signum,  
       siginfo_t   *pAct,  
       void        *pOldAct  
       )
   {
       write(2,
            (const char *)MSG_SIGBUS_IN_HANDLER,  
             strlen((const char *)MSG_SIGBUS_IN_HANDLER)  
             );

       uint32_t faultAddr = (uint32_t)pAct->si_addr;  
       memcpy((void *)buffer,  
             (void *)MSG_SIGBUS_FAULT_ADDR,  
             strlen(MSG_SIGBUS_FAULT_ADDR)  
             );

       write(2,  
            (const char *)MSG_SIGBUS_FAULT_ADDR,  
             strlen((const char *)MSG_SIGBUS_FAULT_ADDR)  
             );  

       sprintf(buffer, "%x\n", faultAddr);  
       write(2, buffer, strlen(buffer));
   }
   ```
4. The problem is the fault adress of instruction (bkpt) is wrong and does not correspond to ARM v7 specification. Here is the console output after the program worked:

   > In SIGBUS handler:
   >   Fault Address: 86b0
   >   In SIGBUS handler:
   >   Fault Address: 86c0
   >   In SIGBUS handler:
   >   Fault Address: 86c0
   >   In SIGBUS handler:
   >   Fault Address: 86c0
   >   In SIGBUS handler:
   >   Fault Address: 86c0
   >   In SIGBUS handler:
   >   Fault Address: 86b0
   >   In SIGBUS handler:
   >   Fault Address: 86a8
   >   In SIGBUS handler:
   >   Fault Address: 86f0

On x86 architecture this sample works correctly. On ARM v7 architecture this sample has a strange behavior.

If I use GDB on ARM v7, he catches my BKPT instruction with correct address.

Maybe someone knows what I do wrong ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The assumption that `si_addr` is *precise* (i.e. the actual address operated on when the fault occurred) for a breakpoint trap is not necessarily true / portable.

You do need to inspect the saved register state, i.e. the third parameter to the signal handler, which can be cast to `ucontext_t*`. The state is *not portable* between CPUs and hence the generic interface only passes a `void *`; GDB inspects it (so that `info registers` works) and extracts the program counter of the fault from there, that's why it's able to point you to the breakpoint instruction.

The situation you're encountering on ARM here is similar as to what you'd get on 64bit x86 if you tried:

```
volatile char *ptr = (char*)0x1234567890abcdef;
char crashme = *ptr;
```

and you expect the fault address in `si_addr` to be `0x1234567890abcdef`. That won't be the case because this address on access will create a `#GPF` not `#PF` fault, and the former doesn't set the fault address register on x86. If you look into the program counter saved as part of `ucontext_t` / `struct sigcontext` (embedded in there) you'll see the faulting instruction address though, and that'll be precise.

Change your signal handler to:

```
void SigBusHandler(
     int  signum,  
     siginfo_t  *pAct,  
     void  *context
    )
{
    struct sigcontext *ctx = &(((ucontext_t*)context)->uc_mcontext);
    uintptr_t fault_address = ctx->arm_pc;    /* that's what you'll see on ARM */
    ...
}
```

Problem, as said, is that figuring out CPU register state necessarily gives you CPU-dependent code. You'll have to make some adaptations / wrappers to keep this portable, like:

```
#if defined(ARM)
#define GET_PC_FROM_CONTEXT(c) (((ucontext_t *)(c))->uc_mcontext.arm_pc)
#elsif defined(__i386__)
define GET_PC_FROM_CONTEXT(c) (((ucontext_t *)(c))->uc_mcontext.eip)
#elsif defined(__amd64__)
define GET_PC_FROM_CONTEXT(c) (((ucontext_t *)(c))->uc_mcontext.rip)
#endif

uintptr_t instr_address = GET_PC_FROM_CONTEXT(context);
```

Hope that helps !