# SIGSEGV si_trapno on ARM

Tags: linux, memory-management, segmentation-fault, arm, signals

I'm writing a signal handler for SIGSEGV on a armhf Debian. It seems that the `si_trapno` member of the `siginfo_t` is not available on ARM (`/usr/include/asm-generic/siginfo.h` from eglibc):

```
[...]
#ifdef __ARCH_SI_TRAPNO
                    int _trapno;    /* TRAP # which caused the signal */
#endif
```

My question is *why*? Why is this macro not defined for ARM? Is the MMU too dumb to pass this  kind of info?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to find out ? Note that `si_addr` also behaves differently on ARM compared to x86, see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5964642/arm-v7-bkpt-instruction-doesnt-work-correctly-on-linux-2-6-35 - if your signal handler wants to drill down into "causes" you likely need to write a specific one for every hardware architecture you want to support.

Answer (score 1):

It is not just ARM. From [`sigaction(2)`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/sigaction.2.html):

```
               int      si_trapno;   /* Trap number that caused
                                        hardware-generated signal
                                        (unused on most architectures) */
```

A quick look at the kernel source code shows it only exists on Alpha, Sparc, and Tile. (The header you are looking at comes from the Linux kernel, as do all the files on `/usr/include/asm`, `/usr/include/asm-generic`, and `/usr/include/linux`).

So, the question is not why this field does not exist on ARM; the question is why would it exist on ARM, since as you can see, the default state for it is not existing. I would guess that on both Alpha and Sparc it was added for compatibility with older Unix variants on the same hardware; I have no idea why Tile decided to add it.