# Multiple calls to sigtrap handler not working

Tags: c, arm, embedded, breakpoints

I have a small application written in C for Linux on ARM which sets up a signal handler for the SIGTRAP signal and is supposed to catch the `bkpt` instruction (via the `TRAP_HWBKPT` code) and effectively skip it.

The handler simply notifies from where the breakpoint was raised and uses an inline epilogue to to redirect codeflow to 4 bytes (due to ARM's RISC architecture) after the breakpoint address (which is the next instruction). I know there should still be some register saving but that's not the problem for now.

What seems to happen is that the first call to a breakpoint-containing function goes fine but the second call doesn't get caught by the custom `sigtrap_handler` anymore and is passed to the default handler instead (causing the process to terminate):

Does anyone know why this happens and how to fix this so i can achieve the goal of calling the handler for every `bkpt` instruction and continuing execution as normal?

```
$ gcc -o break break.c
$ ./break
START
ENTER [0]!
SIGTRAP at 0x856c
EXIT [0]!
ENTER [1]!
Trace/breakpoint trap
```

This is the code in question:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#ifndef TRAP_BRANCH
    #define TRAP_BRANCH 3
#endif

#ifndef TRAP_HWBKPT
    #define TRAP_HWBKPT 4
#endif

static void sigtrap_handler(int sig, siginfo_t* siginfo, void* ptr)
{
    switch(siginfo->si_code)
    {
        case TRAP_HWBKPT:
        {
            printf("SIGTRAP at %p\n", (void*)siginfo->si_addr);

            asm volatile("sub sp, r11, #4\n\t"
                         "pop {r11}\n\t"
                         "sub sp, #4\n\t"
                         "mov pc, %0"
                         :
                         : "r" (siginfo->si_addr + 4) // Proceed to instruction directly after breakpoint
                        );
        }break;

        // misc. SIGTRAP codes (fallthrough)
        case TRAP_BRKPT:
        case TRAP_TRACE:
        case TRAP_BRANCH:
        default:
        {
            exit(-1);
        }break;
    }
}

void dummy_routine(int n)
{
    printf("ENTER [%d]!\n", n);

    // Breakpoint
    asm volatile("bkpt");

    printf("EXIT [%d]!\n", n);
    return;
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i;
    struct sigaction act;

    // Set up sigtrap handler
    memset (&act, 0, sizeof(act));
    act.sa_sigaction = sigtrap_handler;
    act.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;

    if (sigaction(SIGTRAP, &act, 0)) {
        perror("Error: sigaction");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("START\n");

    // Trigger routine containing breakpoint multiple times
    for(i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        dummy_routine(i);
    }

    printf("END\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wait, so you take a signal, pervert the control flow by jumping straight to your code _in the context of the signal handler_, and try to recursively handle more signals without ever returning? I won't claim to be an expert on signals, but that doesn't look right...

Comment: @Notlikethat: It's so bad even the undefined behavior from calling `printf()` in a signal-handler is tame in comparison.

Comment: `sigsetjmp()` and `siglongjmp()` are more likely to succeed at anything close to what you're trying to do.

Comment: [This Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5964642/3156750) seems to touch on everything except actually modifying the saved context.

Comment: @notlikethat: thanks, i found what i was looking for. You can specify:

`struct sigcontext* context = &(((ucontext_t*)ptr)->uc_mcontext);     uintptr_t fault_address = context->arm_pc;`

To get an accurate signal-raising address (GDB inspects the register state in this fashion). And you can set `context->arm_pc += 4` to achieve what i want without causing the faulty behavior due to improper returning from the signal handler.

Comment: The kernel will still believe you are handling a signal and you will get a 'signal-in-signal' whey you take your original approach (say multiple sigbus, etc), so the kernel thinks your process is out of control.  The `ucontext_t` is the proper method to alter the flow when returning from the signal handler.